# more people missing?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Quoted from *What Stars Are Made Of* by Sarah Allen, “Talia went first, and read a wonderful poem she'd written about Langston Hughes, and taught us some of his style and about the Harlem Renaissance. I knew she'd wanted to do someone from Samoa, but there weren't any in our textbook. **More people missing, I guess.** I told her she could find a world-changing Samoan for next semester's presentation, and I thought it was pretty smart of Ms. Trepky to make us look outside the textbook for people to study.”

Could anyone tell me what does the part in bold mean?

Answer (score -2):

I guess (that) more people (were) missing (from...)

This person is saying that there are authors missing from their textbook that should have been in there, or it is missing authors whom they would have liked to be in it. In addition to others already identified as missing.

In a more general sense, the meaning might be that they are missing for a reason or intentionally excluded in an unfair way. In this sense it could be summarizing a phenomenon common to this set of people, and pointing out yet another example of it. But that'd be reading between the lines.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! That helps a lot.